# Is it possible to make hibernate generate SQL code for creation of table's indexes?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to delete many entries from huge table. The only way to do this fast is deleting and then recreating table's indeces. Can I do this with hibernate somehow?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without executing SQL queries. But Hibernate allows executive [SQL queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29).